# Laravel Input::has always returning true

Tags: php, laravel

I know this is probably something simple, but I can't figure out where I went wrong. Essentially I have 2 static php arrays:

```
$array1 = array('Apple', 'Orange');
$array2 = array('Purple', 'Green', 'Yellow');

foreach ($array2 as $arr2){
    foreach ($array1 as $arr1){
        if (Input::has($arr2.$arr1)){
            array_push($testArray, $arr1);
        }
    }  
}
```

The output of the `$testArray` shows that Input::has is outputting twice the number of inputs. So if I select all of the possible inputs (which is 5) it will output each of them twice totaling 10 values. This has lead me to believe that Input::has is evaluating true every time even though it shouldn't be as far as I can tell.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you asking about? Do you have any Inputs set or not here? Please add details to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out!

If you run into something like this, don't get stuck in that loop like I did, look a loop or two higher. I wasn't initializing my variable within this loop but another loop up and didn't realize it for hours...

Answer (score 1):

PHP might think `$arr2.$arr1` is a concatenation:

```
if (Input::has($arr2.$arr1)){
    array_push($testArray, $arr1);
}
```

**Try using this in your dot notation:**

```
if (Input::has("{$arr2}.{$arr1}")){
    array_push($testArray, $arr1);
}
```

Comment: A good suggestion, didn't fix my issue but it's not something I was aware of